# Linked variables - if/then statements in Access

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way in Access to link two variables together across separate tables?

Ex. I have one variable in table A that says Consent1 was signed.

Table B will be a summary table showing which consents are needed. In other words, If Consent1 was signed in table A, table B will show Consent1 is NOT NEEDED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a trigger to update Table B, but if your database is normalized properly there's no need to do that.  Just build a query that does the same thing.  Join Table A to Table B linked on whatever common field they have (I can't tell you exactly how to do that since you've offered no table structure), and then add a field to the query that looks something like this:

```
Consent: IIF([Table A].Consent = "Signed", "Not Needed", "Needed")
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me. But, now I'm trying to set the query up (I'm not too savvy on custom expressions)

I only need Table A then, it seems. I have Table A in the query with variables ID and HWSigned in the query. Then, I made another variable in the query titled "ConsentNeeded" and in the criteria box put "IIf([tblConsents.HWSigned]=Yes,"HW Consent Not Needed","HW Consent Neeed")" but it's returning a parameter box. FYI, HWSigned is a Yes/No variable.

Comment: @ChrisRay - I see that you've asked a few questions here, but have yet to accept an answer (by clicking the checkbox under it) to any of them.  If answers to your questions are useful, please do this as it will encourage people to help you.  If someone has a lot of questions and no accepted answers, they will begin to get ignored.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware. I'll go back and do so for my other questions

Comment: NP.  Each accepted answer also gives you 2 points, so it helps to build your rep as well.